# Move all odd numbers files to a folder

Tags: batch-file

I have a set of images from a camera named like "IMG0001", "IMG0002", ... and I wanted to move all of the odd-numbered images to another folder.

How can I achieve this using batch scripting?

Is it possible to write a script that accepts filenames that don't share a common prefix or the same digit padding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file names fit within the 8.3 convention (base name <=8 chars, no spaces), then the following will work from the command line (double up the percents if used in a batch file).

```
for %F in (*1.jpg *3.jpg *5.jpg *7.jpg *9.jpg) do move "%%F" "newLocation\"
```

But the above may NOT work if the names are long or contain spaces because the long name could have a short name counterpart that ends with an odd or even number. Both DIR and FOR look at both the long and short names when performing pattern matching.

So that leaves an improved version of [kirilloid's solultion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11803514/1012053) that can be adapted to not use a temp file. This adaptation will also work with spaces in the name, mixed case, .jpg in file name as well as extension, etc.

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %F in ('dir /b /a-d *.jpg^|findstr /irc:"[13579]\.jpg$"') do move "%F" "newLocation"
```

Answer (score 1):

[example](http://www.computing.net/answers/windows-xp/counters-with-for-in-batch-files/165116.html) + findstr/regex:

```
DIR /B -D *.jpg | findstr "[02468][.]jpg" > %TEMP%\DIR.LST
FOR /F %%f IN (%TEMP%\DIR.LST) DO (
move %%f new_dir
)
DEL DIR.LST
```

I'd be glad, if someone will tell me, how to do that w/o tmp file. On linux I get used to `xargs` and backticks.

Comment: +1, but see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11804098/1012053). Besides temp file minor inconvenience, your answer has problems if name contains space, upper case .JPG, or if .jpg appears multiple times in name. All fixed with minor tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you want to only get the integer part of your title string, you'd have to regex it and keep only numbers, then check to see if modulus 2 returns true or false, then you can move it

Answer (score -1):

Here's the very non-tech method:

Arrange your files in window, sorted by name, with thumbnails.

Size your window so the the thumbnails fall into two columns.

Use your mouse to window-select only one column.

I have done exactly this with Windows 7.

There is a YouTube video someone made showing this for an older Windows version: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Kr2sTzpFY4

Comment: It's not really a batch script proposed here.

Comment: Two columns is pretty creative, though it assumes there are no gaps in the filenames.

Comment: Forgive me for ignoring that this was request for a batch file.   I used to do this sort of thing with QBasic executables I would create on the fly.  I arrived at this topic looking for a simpler way to do it, and when I found this non-scripted solution, I came back to share it in case others repeat my process.

FYI it occurs to me that by making the window THREE columns, a person could select multiples of three.   You are basically using the GUI interface to sort integers geometrically.